# Using arr.every() on [...HTMLCollection] doesn't return true element change

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, tic-tac-toe, htmlcollection

I'm trying to build a Tic Tac Toe game so I tried to collect the playbox areas in an array by first using `getElementsByClassName()` before using spread operator to convert the collection into an array.
But when I try to use the `arr.every()` method to check if all boxes are played, I still get `false` even after all the boxes are filled

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-sections">
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

First I collected all play boxes.

```
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("play-box");
let numOfBoxes = boxes.length;
```

Then I converted the collection to array and applied the condition to check if all boxes are not empty

```
let boxesArr = [...boxes];
let checkBoxes = boxesArr.every(function(box) {
  return box.innerHTML !== "";
});
```

Then I created a function to check if all boxes are not empty

```
function checkBoard() {
  if (checkBoxes) {
    console.log("All Filled");
  }
}
```

Then I created a funtion to add text to each box and check if all boxes are filled by calling the checkBoard() function onclick.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", addChip);
}
```

The `addChip()` function adds a text to each box as it's clicked, then check if all boxes are filled

```
function addChip() {
  this.innerHTML = "X";
  checkBoard();
}
```

The boxes were filled as they're clicked, and I expected the `checkBoard()` function to return `true` after all boxes are filled, but after all boxes have filled the `checkBoard()` function still returned `false.`

Here's what the full code looks like

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("play-box");
let numOfBoxes = boxes.length;

let boxesArr = [...boxes];
let checkBoxes = boxesArr.every(function(box) {
  return box.innerHTML !== "";
});

function checkBoard() {
  if (checkBoxes) {
    console.log("All Filled");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", addChip);
}

function addChip() {
  this.innerHTML = "X";
  checkBoard();
}
```

```css
.board {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.board-sections {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: #ccc;
  gap: 5px;
  align-content: center;
}

.play-box {
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-sections">
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
    <div class="play-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are pasting your code as disjointed parts where it is not clear how are they being called in the same context: can you share a [mcve] instead?

Comment: Thanks, @Terry, I'd just edited it to include the full code

Comment: Where in your TicTacToe game are you handling the `"O"` circle?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize the code and go straight to what I'm having problems with. I'm only trying to check if all boxes are not empty after every click

Comment: Than your `checkBoxes` should be a **function**, not a **boolean** value

Comment: I don't understand that. I need a boolean value returned, so I use it with the checkBoard() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer your question without having the actual code. Below I assembled a possible scenario that actually works. Maybe it is helpful to you?

```js
const pb=[...document.querySelectorAll(".play-box")];
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b=>{
 b.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  if(b.textContent=="check")
   console.log(pb.every(p=>p.textContent!=""))
  else
   pb.forEach(p=>p.textContent="X");
 })
})
```

```css
.play-box {display:inline-block; width:40px;height:40px; border:1px solid grey}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-sections">
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div><br>
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div><br>
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div>
<div class="play-box"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<button>check</button> <button>fill</button>
```

The point I was trying to make is that the `.textContent` of the `.play-box` elements must be checked *after* they have been filled. OP's original script did the check only once, directly after the page was loaded.

**Explanation:**
The key part in my snippet above is the expression

```
pb.every(p=>p.textContent!="")
```

It returns `true` if all boxes are filled in some way. In your tic-tac-toe game this will need to be executed after each setting of an "X" or an "O".

Your `checkBoard` function should look like this:

```
function checkBoard() {
  if (boxesArr.every(p=>p.textContent!="")) {
    console.log("All Filled");
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `on*` handlers like `onclick` - unless you're creating brand new elements from in-memory. Use addEventListener() instead.

Comment: Yes @Roko, it works just as well with `.addEventListener("click", ...)`  ... ;-)

Comment: Hello Carsen, thanks for your answer, but it's for a Tic Tac Toe Game. The boxes are filled in one after the other as they are clicked. After each box is clicked, it's filled in and then checks if every other box is also filled it. After clicking each box, if the other boxes are filled, it returns true and if one of the box is empty, it returns false.

Comment: Also, don't use `ev.target` like that. If a button has a child, like an icon i.e: `<i class="icon-foo"></i>` and if the click lands on that icon -  the `ev.target.textContent=="check"` will fail. Always use `ev.target.closest()`. And forget about `==`, use the preferred Strict Equality `===` when needed.

Comment: @Iyo, yes,.of course, in the real game the boxes are filled one by one. I did not take the time to actually write the whole game from scratch here. My filling routine was made to simulate a "quick filling" of all boxes.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann PS: in your example you've could have simply used `b.textContent==="X"` - since `b` is already the "this" button. ;)

Comment: I added the `.closest("button")`, as suggested by @RokoC.Buljan. This will make the code more reliable in a general case. For my little snippet - and knowing there weren't any child elements within the buttons - I took the liberty of saving the extra typing work on my smart phone.

Comment: Very good point again, @RokoC.Buljan - changed my answer again. I might have discovered it myself, had I not been too busy typing my comments ... :D

Comment: I have edited my question and the code to add better context. Thanks a lot Carsten and Roko for your help. I'm kind of new to JS, and I'm not familiar with the .textContent property and please if it's not too much can you explain the code in context as to what you're trying to do and how I can use it with my tic tac toe game.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkBoxes` holds a boolean value, not a function:

```js
// This is wrong
let checkBoxes = boxesArr.every(function(box) {
  return box.innerHTML !== "";
});
```

it will only return the value as the state before the game even started. You cannot reuse it like `if (checkBoxes)` during the game and expect an updated value.
Instead, return a function that returns a boolean by using it like `if (checkBoxes()) {`:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".board-box");
const numOfBoxes = boxes.length;

const checkBoxes = () => [...boxes].every((box) => box.textContent.trim() !== "");

function checkBoard() {
  if (checkBoxes()) {
    console.log("All Filled");
  }
}

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", addChip);
});


function addChip() {
  this.textContent = "X";
  checkBoard();
}
```

```css
.board {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.board-sections {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: #ccc;
  gap: 5px;
  align-content: center;
}

.board-box {
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-sections">
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
    <div class="board-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, use `textContent` to return *text* instead of `innerHTML`

---

Additionally you can simplify the code to:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".board-box");
const tot = boxes.length;
let turn = 0;

const isBoxEmpty = (box) => box.textContent.trim() === "";

const checkBoard = () => {
  if (![...boxes].some(isBoxEmpty)) {
    console.log("All Filled");
  }
};

const addChip = (ev) => {
  const box = ev.currentTarget;
  if (!isBoxEmpty(box)) return; // Not an empty box. Exit function here.
  
  box.textContent = (turn % 2) ? "O" : "X";
  checkBoard();
  // Increment turn
  turn += 1;
}

boxes.forEach((box) => box.addEventListener("click", addChip));
```

```css
.board {
  font: 14vmin/1 sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.board-box {
  height: 20vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
  <div class="board-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko. Your answer help me put Carsten's in perspective as to how I could apply it to my tic-tac-toe game. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Iyo you're very welcome. Added another code sample with some improvement and a heads-up addon. Far from a working Tic-Tac-Toe game - but I don't want to spoil the fun ;) Feel tree to ask is something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to add them. My goal's to use as simplified code as possible. Thanks again for your help, Roko.